# radarchart adding zero line

Tags: r, plot

Made this function because i need multiple plots and here is the code. I am trying to add a line that shows where the 0 is on the radar chart.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Want this to be unfilled. I have attached images as reference.

```
library(fmsb)
colors = #list of colors
finalColors <- colors[1:numberofloops]

reateRadarChart <- function(data, color = "#00AFBB", 
                                        vlabels = colnames(data), vlcex = 0.7,
                                        caxislabels = NULL, title = NULL, ...){
  radarchart(
    data, axistype = 1,
    pcol = color, pfcol = scales::alpha(color, 0.75), plwd = 2, plty = 1,
    cglcol = "grey", cglty = 1, cglwd = 0.75,
    axislabcol = FALSE, 
    vlcex = vlcex, vlabels = vlabels,
    caxislabels = caxislabels, title = title,
    pty = 32, ...
  )
}

for(i in 1:numberofloops){
  png(filename=paste(i,"png)
  createRadarChart(
    data = data[c(1, 2, i+2), ], #1 and 2 are min and max
    color = finalColors[i], title = titles[i,]
  )
  dev.off()
}
```

tried adding zero vector and plotting but can't get it to work (want zero vector line black and unfilled)